# Index use in Gridview for Editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, c

I have a Gridview that has many pages. I order it by an ID number in descending order which is displayed.  When I try to edit the row with an Edit button, the index I get does not match the row I clicked on. How do I tie the row I clicked Edit on to the index the gvRowEditing method recieves?

Tne RowEdit method gets an GridViewEditEventArgs object which has NewEditIndex but that grabs an index regarldess of how the rows are ordered.  How would I access the CommandArgument which I can tie to an ID or even use the existing RowEdit method but with the proper index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this.

```
protected void gvPosts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvPosts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //database code, I use a method called DataBound()
    }
```

Then to cancel it you should be able to use..

```
protected void gvPosts_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvPosts.EditIndex = -1;
        //used the same DataBound()
    }
```

Hope this helps.